# Forward converter currrent flow

Tags: electrical-engineering

If we have the following forward converter:
[image]

when $Q_1$ is on we have:

[image]

Why is it that the Diodes $D_1$ and $D_3$ are off?

Similarly when $Q_1$ is off why is Diode $D_2$ off?

[image]